# How to Capture all currently running batch scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Case: A lot of agents on one machine execute the following command (from within a batch file):

```
start program %param%
```

Toughies:

1. Subject machine can only run batch script (no Powershell, no C, no Java)
2. Logging (the mechanism through which before submission of the Start, the starting scripts specifically logs the event somewhere) is a LAST resort.

How can a program running in parallel "scan" all the batch processes that have been Started? By Scanning, I mean capture the window title text.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: As per suggestion by @aschipfl

This [link](https://superuser.com/questions/18830/is-there-a-command-in-windows-like-ps-aux-in-unix) gives you information of how to look at processes running on Windows using the `tasklist` command

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>tasklist /?

TASKLIST [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]]
     [/M [module] | /SVC | /V] [/FI filter] [/FO format] [/NH]
```

The `/FI` option can be used to just get the ones you are interested in.

Hope this helps..

Comment: You should mention the `tasklist` command you linked; remember that external links might become invalid someday...

Answer (score 0):

```
tasklist /v
```

is how. Use a filter for batch. Open a admin command prompt and run this in a different one.

```
tasklist /v /fi "windowtitle eq Administrator: Command Prompt"
```

Comment: This will only find running command prompt windows that currently have the title "Administrator: Command Prompt" - this won't pick up the vast majority of open command prompt windows. Use `"imagename eq cmd.exe"` instead.

Comment: He wants a specific window title not all cmd processes.

Comment: Man, I don't know how I missed that. He should really add that to the question title.